# Open file Office doc on a url through command line (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, command-line, terminal, ms-office

I am trying to build a Java applet that will automatically load an Office file from a url and open it with the right desktop application on Mac Os.

For the moment, I am looking for the command line that will help me do that (without any use of Java).
I can already open a local file on my mac with :
`open -a Libreoffice http://localhost:3000/myfile.docx`
But it goes on my web browser and tries to load the url, whereas I actually need Libreoffice to open the file from the url.
And open -a doesn't seem to be the answer that I want ( http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macpowerpoint/how-to-startup-powerpoint-from-command-line/af3a6667-ab80-418b-9dfe-1c8ae9436d94 )

There is also another way of launching the right app by going in the right application folder for instance :
`Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Word`

Has anybody any idea of how I could do that?

Many thanks in advance

P

Answer (score 0):

Try using `curl` (or Java) to download the file to a temporary location first, then `open`:

```
cd mytempdir  // specify your working directory
curl -O http://mywebsite.com/mydoc.docx  // download file to temp dir
open mydoc.docx
```

Comment: Many thanks whiskeyspider, the only problem is that I want to open the file from the server and not open the file from a local directory. Because I'm using webdav and if I download the file in a local directory, I lose the connection to webdav.